# Clicker Game LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

I need help with a save function for my clicker game. So far my game is EXTREMELY small but I thought I had better the autosaving out of the way before I go any further.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var cookies = 0;
var cursors = 0;
var workers = 0;

function cookieClick(number){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
};

function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(cookies >= cursorCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        cursors = cursors + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
     cookies = cookies - cursorCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = cursors;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    };
    var nextcursorCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cursors));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = nextcursorCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};

function buyWorker(){
 var workerCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.1,workers));
 if(cookies >= workerCost){
  workers = workers + 1;
  cookies = cookies - workerCost;
  document.getElementById('workers').innerHTML = workers;
 };
 var nextworkerCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.1,workers));
 document.getElementById('workerCost').innerHTML = nextworkerCost;
}

window.setInterval(function(){
 cookieClick(cursors);
 }, 1000);

window.setInterval(function(){
 cookieClick(workers);
 }, 250);



//SAVE AND LOAD THE GAME
function saveGame(){
    printMessageLine("Saved.");
    localStorage['shittyInc_save'] = btoa(JSON.stringify(game));
}

function loadGame() {

    var save_data = localStorage['shittyInc_save']
    printMessageLine("Loaded.");
    console.log(save_data);
    if (!save_data) return;
    console.log(save_data);

    game = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['shittyInc_save']))
}
```

NOTE: my current save fuction does not work.

I do NOT intend on having and import save feature. Autosave is all I am looking for help with and I will happily include your twitter or whatever in the credits if you would like me to.

Comment: hmmmmm if you really care about abusing, you should not calculate stuff like "worker costs" js side...the player can manipulate it easily. You should proove that stuff always serverside to prevent cheating

Comment: so far the client gets all of the js codes serverd, he could inject some hacks like `workerCost = 0`

Comment: Just use `setInterval` as you already are for autoclicks. Btw, if user wants to cheat, nothing will stop him from it, as long as game logic accessible locally.

Comment: It is not hard to cheat when all they need to do is change localstorage. :) Just call your save method when things change or on an interval.

Comment: `setInterval(function(){saveGame()}, 60000)`

Comment: My current savegame function doesn't work, I should of specified that in the question sorry.

Comment: It is because you use it wrong. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage. TL;DR: `localStorage.getItem(name)` to retrieve data, `localStorage.setItem(name, data)` to store data in string format. Your code uses properties of DOMStorage object instance, which is created anew each time you load/reload page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you make a dictionary and save it to localStorage, like this:

```js
function saveGame() {
  var savedGame = {
    cookies: cookies,
    cursors: cursors,
    workers: workers
  }
  localStorage.setItem("savedGame", JSON.stringify(savedGame));
 }
```

For the load, you use this:

```js
function loadGame() {
  var savedGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gameSave"))
}
```

To autosave and autoload, do this:

```js
// Save
setInterval(saveGame, 1000);

// Load
window.onload function() {
  loadGame();
  document.getElementById("cookies").innerHTML = cookies;
  document.getElementById("cursors").innerHTML = cursors;
  document.getElementById("cursorCost").innerHTML = cursorCost;
  document.getElementById("workers").innerHTML = workers;
  document.getElementById("workerCost").innerHTML = workerCost;
}
```

Then every second, the game will save and once you refresh, your game will load.